# MySQL : IF condition from a REQUEST

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join

I have a question concerning mySQL :

I have two tables.

In the table1, I have these column : idprojet, datedebut, datefin. I have only 5 entries (5 idprojet, 5 datedebut, 5 datefin).

In the table 2, I have the same 5 idprojet, but with various datedebut and various datefin.

I need to fin a way to know if the smaller "datedebut" for each project in table 2 is smaller than the datedebut from table1, and if the biggest "datefin" for each project in table 2 is bigger than the datefin from table2.

I wrote this request to join the tables together with the datas I needed, but I'm stuck there. I don't know if I have to write an IF statement, and if so, what is should look like.. Thanks !

```
    SELECT Table1.idprojet,table1.datedebut, table1.datefin, MIN(table2.dateDEBUT), MAX(table2.dateFIN)
FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.idProjet = table1.idProjet
GROUP BY table2.idProjet
```

**EDIT**

[image: This is an example of table1]

[image: This is an example of table 2]

The outpout would be something like :

[image: The outpout would be something like]

Comment: Can you post a sample of the table? And what the desired output would look like?

Comment: you can use **CASE** statements to check conditions in MYSQL. you can check the document reference from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: Hi! Done (I edit the question)

Answer (score 1):

Using case statement will do the if/else comparison. I think this will help though.

`SELECT Table1.idprojet,
case when table1.datedebut < table2.tab2min then 'False'
else 'True' end as dateDebutComparison,
case when table2.tab2max > table1.dateFin then 'True'
else 'False' end as dateFinComparison
FROM table1 
JOIN (select idProjet, MIN(dateDEBUT) tab2min, MAX(dateFIN) tab2max FROM table2 GROUP BY idProjet) table2
ON table2.idProjet = table1.idProjet`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It says that the second case isn't valid at this position, would you happen to know why ?

Comment: There was a missing comma, I hope that was the fix

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work, but I just realized that the "datedebut" and "datefin" were "date variable". I don't know if it changes anything, knowing that the format isn't an int but a date.. ?

Comment: It gives me : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'etapexprojet.dateFin' in 'field list'

Comment: Tweaked the query. The second case statement needed to be updated to reflect the alias from the subquery.